# Loop to convert/extract json data in pandas DataFrame not working

Tags: python, json, pandas, loops, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to follow through an EDA walkthrough and convert/extract json data in the dataframe by using a loop to take care of the columns with json data. I'm doing this by setting up a list for the loop to iterate through and then setting up the for loop to load the json data and extract the name field for each row of each column.

After working on the first column in the list, it throws a 'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'' error.

I've tried modifying the list by adding and removing columns to see where it fails, and it always works on the first column, but gives up after. This remains true for a list of one column.

I think the problem is that the 'json.loads(data)' that is being passed is somehow still pointing to the results of the last loop (since the json from the last loop was converted/extracted into a list). But I'm not sure if this is the case, and if it is, how to fix it.

Here's the code:

```
json_fields = ['genres', 'production_countries', 'spoken_languages']

for field in json_fields:
    print(field)
    movies_df[field] = movies_df[field].apply(lambda data:[row['name'] for row in json.loads(data)])
```

Here is the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-cc13bd0423f3> in <module>()
      3 for field in json_fields:
      4     print(field)
----> 5     movies_df[field] = movies_df[field].apply(lambda data:[row['name'] for row in json.loads(data)])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2549             else:
   2550                 values = self.asobject
-> 2551                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2552 
   2553         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-15-cc13bd0423f3> in <lambda>(data)
      3 for field in json_fields:
      4     print(field)
----> 5     movies_df[field] = movies_df[field].apply(lambda data:[row['name'] for row in json.loads(data)])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346         if not isinstance(s, (bytes, bytearray)):
    347             raise TypeError('the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
--> 348                             'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))
    349         s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
    350 

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'
```

And here is a link to the resulting table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg2fP.jpg

Genres is the column that worked, and the other two are examples of the columns that didn't

Edit: Here is the source for the table that I'm using: https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata/

Comment: Your lambda expression returns [row['name'] for row in json.loads(data)] for each of the rows. I guess you rather want that the name of each document is assigned to another row, right?

Comment: @jottbe, I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by document. Do you mean 'data' to refer to the data housed in each row as it goes through the for loop?

Comment: So is the goal to convert each highlighted column in the image to a list of names rather then dictionaries?

Comment: @exlo, by document I mean json document (the same as row). Sorry for mixing the terms.

Comment: @jottbe, no worries. If I'm understanding correctly, then yes, I would rather want the name of each (row['name']) to be assigned to another set of rows (the which would be the next column in the loop).

Comment: @exlo Can you add how you are reading in the dataframe, I am not getting the same issue when I use `movies_df = pandas.Dataframe.from_csv(filename)` then running the same code.

Comment: That's so interesting, it does work. I'm reading it in with `movies_df = pd.read_csv('./TMDB/tmdb_5000_movies.csv')`, and when I used `pd.DataFrame.from_csv` like you said, something else failed in the notebook. When I went back and change it to back to `pd.read_csv`, the loop performed as expected (after a reset the kernel and ran all cells again). Is there a reason for that? I often reset and ran all cells, so I wonder why using `pd.DataFrame.from_csv` fixed the problem, whether I keep it or revert back to `pd.read_csv` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

So I think that the column "genre" was a string representing of JSON, while the columns "production_countries" and "spoken_languages" are lists that either contain string representations of JSON or are already parsed as python dictionaries.

Try changing the loop to

```
for field in json_fields:
    print(field)
    print(type(movies_df[field][0]))
    print(type(movies_df[field][0][0]))
```

Based on the output there are a couple of solutions

#### 1. The "production_countries" and "spoken_languages" are lists of strings

If the loop above gives you something like

```
production_countries
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
```

Then each row in "production_countries" is a list and each element in the list is a string that should be able to be parsed as JSON using the following code.

```
for field in json_fields:
    if field == 'genres':
        movies_df[field] = movies_df[field].apply(lambda data: [row['name'] for row in json.loads(data)])
    elif field == 'production_countries':
        movies_df[field] = movies_df[field].apply(lambda data: [json.loads(row)['name'] for row in data])
```

#### 2. The "production_countries" and "spoken_languages" are lists of python dictionaries

If the first loop instead gives you something like

```
production_countries
<class 'list'>
<class 'dict'>
```

Then each row on "production_countries" is a list and each element in the list is a dictionary. Then the following should work

```
for field in json_fields:
    if field == 'genres':
        movies_df[field] = movies_df[field].apply(lambda data: [row['name'] for row in json.loads(data)])
    elif field == 'production_countries':
        movies_df[field] = movies_df[field].apply(lambda data: [row['name'] for row in data])
```

#### Summary

If the above doesn't work then the columns may be made up of other data structures. If the above does work, it may be best to change how the data is loaded into the panda dataframe instead of using the above solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tip! It seems like the output for type is actually 'production_countries <class 'str'> <class 'str'>'. This is also true for the field 'genres'. Both solutions are leading to errors (solution 1 throws a 'Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)' error) and solution 2 is showing the same json string error from my original post.

Comment: Interesting, do you have the source JSON that you used to make the dataframe or a REST endpoint that I could test with? @exlo

Comment: Yes! It an be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata/. I'll update the body of my question as well.